# Complex SQL Query Using Group By

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
User   Referred By
A      FB
B      Google
C      Twitter
A      FB
B      Friend
D      FB
E      FB
B      Friend
A      Friend
```

I am interested in output like:

```
User referred_by count  
A    FB          2
A    Friend      1
B    Friend      2
B    Google      1
```

and so on.

I have made several queries but not able to get this as my output, I am a beginner in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, maybe with some modifications depending in your `RDBMS`. The `User` is reserved word in must `RDBMS`, you must manage it accordingly.

```
SELECT User, ReferredBy, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM tbl
GROUP BY User, ReferredBy
```

Comment: works, changed my column name too, after reading it is not good practice to use reserved keyword. Thanks.